# Change date format in Oracle Reports 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, report

I have a report that requires the BeginDate and EndDate parameters to be in the form DD-MON-YYYY. In the report header, it is required that the BeginDate and EndDate parameters be displayed in the format MM/DD/YYYY. I've tried adding another begin and end parameter and using the input mask and format mask to try and convert it, but the report breaks. Anyone have any clues?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TO_CHAR](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) to format your date.

To change the date according to your format i.e. DD-MON-YYYY, You can do like this:

```
TO_CHAR(col_name,'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Check Out the **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9636a/2)**

Comment: The date is in the right format for the query. I just need to convert the date once it is in the report.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have User Parameter with input mask as below-

[image]

In the report you can have something like

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(:P_1,'MM/DD/RR') from dual;
```

for both `BeginDate` and `EndDate`.

Comment: It won't let me put a query in that field.

Comment: You can't put this query in "that field". You could write a small program unit and have the query inside the program unit and call it from the report to get the properly formatted dates.

Comment: can you give me an example of how to do this in the AfterParamForm Trigger?